# how to use processing library in Android

Tags: android, extends, processing

Do I have to extends PApplet class? I try to avoid creating an applet, since android has its avtivity. But it seems if I do not create an applet, I can not use its method.
Does anybody has ideas on using Processing in Android? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Processing has native Android support in the latest version (1.5.1). You just need to change the IDE view into "Android" from "Standard".

Comment: Yes, it has native support. Since I my application does not only rely on processing library, I need to develop it in Eclipse environment. In this case, do I have to extends PApplet?

Answer (score 0):

additional stuff to the first answer:
<< Processing has native Android support in the latest version (1.5.1). You just need to change the IDE view into "Android" from "Standard".

when you click Run button it automatically uses Android.  However you have to download the emulator thing from the website (SDK http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and you have to tell the Processing where the application is so that it sends your sketch to Android.